# State of tomcat 9.0 server unknow or in transition

Tags: eclipse, tomcat9

I got this error below while trying to clean server workspace. Most actions from server menu in servers views were greyed.

```
The state of the tomcat v9.0 at localhost is in transition or unknown. Try again when the server has reached a stable state.
```

I found nothing about this while Googling the error.

Restarting Eclipse solved the issue.

How do you refresh server state from eclipse without restarting Eclispe (which takes some time) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You switch to Intellij IDEA :(